# How to adjust the horizontal spacing of a table to get a good horizontal distribution?

Tags: tables, tabularx, siunitx

How can I adjust the horizontal spacing of my table so the columns for Object, Values A, and Values B are evenly or better distributed? So far, I always used the `X` column type from `tabularx` to get good looking results, but this time I need to align some numbers with the help of the `siunitx` `S` column type and the horizontal alignment looks horrible as you can see.
I don't mind some white space between the columns of Object, Values A and Values B. The columns "inside" Values A for example should be closer together like in the minimum working example down below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,                                   
    DIV=12,                                 
    paper=A4,                                                       
    parskip=half,                                           
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Some Values}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XSXSSXS}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Object} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Values A} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Values B}\\ 
        \midrule
        Lorem           & 70,50 & bis & 60,50         & 60,50 & bis & 50,50 \\
        Ipsum           & 60,50 & bis & 50,50         & 50,50 & bis & 40,50 \\ 
        Lorem           & 50,50 & bis & 40,50         & 40,50 & bis & 30,50 \\ 
        Ipsum           & 40,50 & bis & 30,50         & 30,50 & bis & 20,50 \\ 
        Lorem           & 30,50 & bis & 20,50         & 20,50 & bis & 10,50 \\ 
        Ipsum           & 20,50 & bis & 10,50         & 10,50 & bis & 00,50 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If you change the `X` columntypes to `l` and use `@{\extracolsep{\fill}` you can get the following result, which already looks better.

[image]

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Some Values}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}SlSSlS}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Object} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Values A} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Values B}\\ 
        \midrule
        Lorem           & 70,50 & bis & 60,50         & 60,50 & bis & 50,50 \\
        Ipsum           & 60,50 & bis & 50,50         & 50,50 & bis & 40,50 \\ 
        Lorem           & 50,50 & bis & 40,50         & 40,50 & bis & 30,50 \\ 
        Ipsum           & 40,50 & bis & 30,50         & 30,50 & bis & 20,50 \\ 
        Lorem           & 30,50 & bis & 20,50         & 20,50 & bis & 10,50 \\ 
        Ipsum           & 20,50 & bis & 10,50         & 10,50 & bis & 00,50 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option without `tabularx`. I don't see a reason for all of this whitespace and would advise against it, though.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Some Values}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ r *{2}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} S @{\extracolsep{0pt}~bis~} S} }
        \toprule
        \textbf{Object} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Values A} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Values B}\\ 
        \midrule
        Lorem & 70,50 & 60,50 & 60,50 & 50,50 \\
        Ipsum & 60,50 & 50,50 & 50,50 & 40,50 \\ 
        Lorem & 50,50 & 40,50 & 40,50 & 30,50 \\ 
        Ipsum & 40,50 & 30,50 & 30,50 & 20,50 \\ 
        Lorem & 30,50 & 20,50 & 20,50 & 10,50 \\ 
        Ipsum & 20,50 & 10,50 & 10,50 & 00,50 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thank you for this interesting answer! I didn't know about the \extracolsep command yet and that you can multiply the column definitions. There is a small problem with this solution: If you change Values A to a larger text, the spacing before and after bis isn't equal anymore,

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions that use a basic `tabular` environment and automate creating en-dashes between the pairs of numbers.

The only important difference between the tables is that the first uses the `l` column type for the first column, whereas the second uses a `p{5cm}` column type. The second solution may be preferable if the contents of cells in the first column can be long. (Your real table won't feature the words "Lorem" and "Ipsum", right?) Either way, I can't see a good reason for using a `tabularx` environment with a target width of `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=12,paper=A4,parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}{S[table-format=2.2]}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Some Values}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l 
                        T @{\,--\,} T 
                        T @{\,--\,} T @{}}
    \toprule
    Object & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Values A} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Values B} \\ 
    \midrule
    Lorem           & 70,50 & 60,50         & 60,50 & 50,50 \\
    Ipsum           & 60,50 & 50,50         & 50,50 & 40,50 \\ 
    Lorem           & 50,50 & 40,50         & 40,50 & 30,50 \\ 
    Ipsum           & 40,50 & 30,50         & 30,50 & 20,50 \\ 
    Lorem           & 30,50 & 20,50         & 20,50 & 10,50 \\ 
    Ipsum           & 20,50 & 10,50         & 10,50 & 00,50 \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    
\bigskip

    \begin{tabular}{@{} p{5cm} 
                        T @{\,--\,} T 
                        T @{\,--\,} T @{}}
    \toprule
    Object & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Values A} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Values B} \\ 
    \midrule
    Lorem           & 70,50 & 60,50         & 60,50 & 50,50 \\
    Ipsum           & 60,50 & 50,50         & 50,50 & 40,50 \\ 
    Lorem           & 50,50 & 40,50         & 40,50 & 30,50 \\ 
    Ipsum           & 40,50 & 30,50         & 30,50 & 20,50 \\ 
    Lorem           & 30,50 & 20,50         & 20,50 & 10,50 \\ 
    Ipsum           & 20,50 & 10,50         & 10,50 & 00,50 \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question: If I understand your additional formatting objective correctly, I think it's necessary to change the current setup, *viz.*,

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} 
                l 
                T 
                @{\,--\,} 
                T 
                T 
                @{\,--\,} 
                T 
                @{}}
\toprule
...
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

to

```
\begin{tabular*}{0.7\textwidth}{@{} % set a suitable target width
                    l 
                    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                    T 
                    @{\,--\,\extracolsep{0pt}} 
                    T 
                    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                    T 
                    @{\,--\,\extracolsep{0pt}} 
                    T @{}}
\toprule
... 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
```

In short, while it's feasible in principle, it's not something I'd recommend doing in practice.

Comment: Thank you very much for this interesting answer. I didn't know one could automate the creation of en-dashes like that! Is there some sort of \hfill command that i could use to add a equall space: @{}l \hfill T @{\,--\,} T \hfill T @{\,--\,} T ?